# Python-3.4 - lxml compilation failed - cannot find -lpython3.4m

Tags: compilation, lxml, python-3.4

Trying to compile lxml 3.3.3 with python-3.4.1, gcc fails with

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/jeby6372/pack/lxml-3.3.4/src/lxml/includes -I/opt/python3/include/python3.4m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -L/usr/lib -L. -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -lpython3.4m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.4m
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any idea ?

note : I have the same problem trying to compile netiface-0.10.3 and probably with other python3 packages

Answer (score 0):

I had *exactly* the same error while running `$ pip install psycopg2` inside a `pyvenv` (python virtual environment). The source of the problem was that the `pyvenv` that I had made was incorrect, thus the paths were all wrong.

I created a new `pyvenv` and restarted the process and everything went fine.

I hope this will help you :)